# Quotient space $N=\mathbb{R}^{2}/L$ is Hausdorff (or $T_1$) iff $L$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, separation-axioms

Let $L$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and let $N = \mathbb{R}^{2}/L$ be the quotient space obtained by identifying all points in $L$ to a single point. I need to prove that 
$N$ is Hausdorff $\longleftrightarrow$ $N$ is $T_{1}$ $\longleftrightarrow$ $L$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I know that a if $N$ is Hausdorff then every finite point set is closed and therefore $N$ satisfies the $T_{1}$ condition. I also know that if $N$ is Hausdorff then for each pair $n_{1},n_{2}$ of distinct points of $N$, there are disjoint neighborhoods $U_{1},U_{2}$ of $n_{1},n_{2}$ respectively.

Thanks

Comment: Special case of the theorem that if $X$ is regular Hausdorff and $A$ in $X$ is closed, then $X/A$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Where did you find this theorem?

Comment: Found it!, Thank you, that was very useful, indeed

Comment: Try to prove it yourself, it is not difficult.

Comment: yup, that's what I did jijijiji